# Simple calculation of covariance for a discrete random process

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$U$ is uniform r.v. $[-\pi,\pi]$ and $X_n$ a discrete time random process $X_n=\cos(nU)$ and $n$ greater than or equal to one.

\begin{align}\operatorname{Cov}\big(X(n),X(n+m)\big)=E\Big(\cos(nU)\cos\big((n+m)U\big)\Big)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) E\Big(\cos\big((2n+m)U\big)+\cos(mU)\Big)\\
= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)E\Big(\cos\big((2n+m)U\big)\Big) + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)E\big(\cos(mU)\big)\\
 = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{(2n+m)2\pi}\right) \Big[\sin \big((2n+m)\pi\big) - \sin\big(-(2n+m)\pi\big)\Big] + 
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2m\pi}\right) \big[\sin (m\pi) - \sin(-m\pi)\big] = 0.\end{align}

Apparently the answer should be $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \delta(m)$.

What am I missing?

Comment: When $m=0$ you cannot divide by $m$, while $\frac{1}{2}E(\cos(mU)) =\frac12$

Comment: Isnt m, like n, always greater than or equal to one?

Comment: When $m \not = 0$ then $\delta(m)=0$ so apparently the answer thinks $m =0$ is possible

Comment: @user1952009: It is not clear to me that $X_n$ and $X_{n+m}$ are independent is they are calculated using the same value of $U$.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't understand that,

Comment: @user1952009 and Henry: I know my solution is correct as far as the second row. I guess Henry must be right about that m can be zero. Seems a little odd tho :) when n has to be greater than or equal to one

Comment: What is odd in wanting to be able to compute Cov(X(3),X(3)), say, for which n=3 and m=$___$?

Comment: @Did lol, yeah, you are definitely right. You should not do math, or rather, post about math when you are this hung over...